# Way to speed up NSAttributedString rendering for use in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsattributedstring

I have an attributed string with maybe 5 attributes that set font weight, color, and spacing in certain areas. It's not terribly verbose but it is being rendered for every cell. The drop in performance is painfully noticeable. I'm talking going from 9ms to 2ms to render a cell just by commenting out one line:

```
self.textLabel.attributedString = attrStr;
```

So, I tried generating the attributed strings before hand and caching them in an array but that doesn't change anything because the performance difference is in the actual rendering of the string.

On newer devices it's no big deal, but I'm testing on a 5c and it's just not gonna fly.

Any advice?

Comment: Try simpler formatting or maybe splitting the label into two.

Comment: OK so it's definitely simply because rendering an attributed string takes way more work on the processor than static font/color/whatever? I guess this would explain why there was no NSAttributedString until like 2011.

Comment: I didn't say that at all, you did. You asked for advice. So I gave you something simple to try based on your own observations.